# About convergence of measures with weak $^*$ topology

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

We denote by $\mathcal{M}(X)$ the set of all Borel probability measure of $X$. We know that this set is a compact metrizable convex space and its topology is weak $^*$ topology defined by the convergence $\mu_n\to \mu$ if and only if $\int \varphi d \mu_n\to \int \varphi d\mu$ for every continuous map $\varphi:X\to \mathbb{R}$.

Let $\mu_m\to \mu$ and $\mu(A)>0$ for some a non-empty subset $A\subseteq X$. 
Can we say that there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mu_m(A)>0$ for $m>N$?

Answer (score 4):

let $(r_n)$ be a sequence of rational numbers converging to an irrational number $x$. Then $\delta_{x_n} \to \delta_x$ in weak* topology and $\delta_x (\{x\})=1$ but $\delta_{x_n}(\{x\})=0$ for all $n$.

However the conclusion holds if $A$ is open.

Comment: This actually works for any convergent sequence that is not eventually equal to its limit, you don't need irrational vs. rational.

Answer (score 2):

If $X=[0,1]$ and $$\mu_n = \frac{1}{{n+1}} \sum_{k=0}^n\delta_{k/n} $$ where $\delta_x$ is the Dirac mass at $x$, $\mu_n$ converges weak* to Lebesgue measure, but if $A = A \setminus \mathbb Q$ with positive Lebesgue measure, then $\mu_n (A) = 0$ for all $n$.